# Issue in saving PDF in my iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, pdf

In my app, am getting my PDF as a URL from web service. Now i would like to store it in my iPad and open in adobe Reader App.. i used the following code to save it and just opened it in a webView

```
NSData *pdfData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[
                                                         NSURL URLWithString:socialURLString]];

// Store the Data locally as PDF File
NSString *resourceDocPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[
                                                              [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent]
                                                              stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"
                                                              ]];

NSString *filePath = [resourceDocPath
                      stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"pdfOne.pdf"];
[pdfData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

// Now create Request for the file that was saved in your documents folder
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[web setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[web setDelegate:self];
[web loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Now assuming that it got stored in my iPad, i opened Adobe Reader app and it didnot display the PDF. What am i doing wrong.?

Comment: Are you sure it gets stored in the documents folder properly?

Comment: No.. I dono whether it got stored or not.

Comment: @rmaddy: Can i access the pdf from outside my app? i mean, i wanna view the saved PDF with Adobe Reader app.. Is it possible frnd?

Answer (score 0):

The resource bundle is a readonly directory along with its content files. so you should write the file in either temporary directory or some cache directory

```
////In temporary directory
NSString *tmpFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.pdf",NSTemporaryDirectory(),@"pdfOne"];

NSString * filePath = tmpFilePath;
```

or

```
///In caches directory.
    NSString *cacheDirectoryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]; 
    NSString *tmpFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.pdf",cacheDirectoryPath,@"pdfOne"];

    NSString * filePath = tmpFilePath;
```

Comment: Can i access the pdf from outside my app? i mean, i wanna view the saved PDF with Adobe Reader app.. Is it possible frnd?

Comment: you can save in Caches or temporary Directory and access the same.

Comment: Yeah i have used ur above code to save the PDF to cache. Still when i open Adobe Reader, the saved PDF is not displayed there.. Wat am i doing wrong?

Comment: Is the PDF downloaded in the cache directory?

Comment: how to check whether it is downloaded in cache?